# Import not being picked up by component file

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on a simple Angular 2 project, I have all my imports working within my app.module.ts file as below

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { StockListComponent } from './stock-list/stock-list.component';

import { routing } from "./app-routing.module";
import { StockItemComponent } from './stock-item/stock-item.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './profile/profile.component';
import { DeviceConfigurationComponent } from './device-configuration/device-configuration.component';
import { StockStatusComponent } from './stock-status/stock-status.component';


import {Calendar, Dialog, Button, InputSwitch, Dropdown, Growl, DataTable, SelectButtonModule} from 'primeng/primeng';
import {JwtHelper, AuthHttp, tokenNotExpired} from "angular2-jwt";

import {AuthService} from './auth.service';
import {DataService} from './data.service';

@NgModule({
 declarations: [
  AppComponent,
  StockListComponent,
  StockItemComponent,
  ProfileComponent,
  DeviceConfigurationComponent,
  StockStatusComponent
],
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  FormsModule,
  HttpModule,
  routing,
  DataTable,
  Calendar,
  Dialog,
  Button,
  InputSwitch,
  Dropdown,
  Growl,
  JwtHelper,
  AuthHttp,
  SelectButtonModule
],
providers: [
  AuthService,
  DataService
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

however i get this error in my console relating to one of my component.ts files, that the names cannot be found even tho they have been imported in the app.module.ts

error

ERROR in [default] /Users/~/src/app/stock-list/stock-list.component.ts:42:26 
Cannot find name 'AuthService'.

Comment: Are you importing `AuthService` in `stock-list.component.ts`? If so, could you show how you're doing this?

Comment: You still need to import AuthService in stock-list.component. But you don't need to include it as a provider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to call methods on `AuthService` you will have to import it again in your component and inject it, so that it can be referenced.

For example:

```
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service'; // edit path according to your structure
```

Next, you should inject the service in your component like so:

```
constructor(private auth: AuthService) { }
```

Now you can reference the AuthService in your component's methods, e.g:

```
myComponentMethod() {
   this.auth.logout();
}
```